# Automatically updating ORCID, etc, from arXiv?

Tags: arxiv, digital-researcher-id, automation

Generally, whenever I write an article, I will always upload it to arXiv first. So, my list of publications on arXiv is essentially the most official version of my publication record.

Is there a way to automatically update my profiles from other websites (ORCID, Google Scholar, ResearcherID) directly from my arXiv record? (I do have an arXiv author identifier). i.e. whenever I upload a new article to arXiv, it will automatically be populated on those other platforms I mentioned.

Comment: I don't know the answer, sorry. I known that Zenodo does this, through DataCite. https://about.zenodo.org/principles/ https://blog.datacite.org/explaining-the-datacite-orcid-auto-update/

Comment: Does anyone have advice about how to write a small script to do such things for me?

Answer (score 4):

Google scholar will add anything it finds to your profile automatically. Usually it is more necessary to clean up (e.g. if a name of a preprint does not match the published version exactly) than to add more.

ORCID only lists papers that are published by journals - no preprints. But it also does this automatically (and does a good job - you can help if you use your ORCID during submission).

I don't know about research gate.

Comment: ORCID allows me to add preprints from arXiv, which I have done. Should I not be doing this?

Comment: Oh, I did not know this. In most cases, preprint get published at some point. Then you should clean up the ORCID page to avoid duplicates.